# How to get value of h:inputText, when bound in JSF?

Tags: jsf

How can I get 2 `h:inputTextValue` from this?

```
<h:dataTable cellspacing="0" value="#{managerManagedBean.lstMatch}" var="m" binding="#{managerManagedBean.datatableMatch}">
    <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Team One</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{m.teamOneName}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Match Score</f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{m.teamOneResult}" style="width: 20px; text-align: center" binding="#{input}"></h:inputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{m.teamTwoResult}" style="width: 20px; text-align: center"></h:inputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Half Time</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{m.haveHalfTime}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Team Two</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{m.teamTwoName}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Match Date</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{m.matchDate}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Control</f:facet>
        <h:commandButton action="#{managerManagedBean.update(m, input.value)}" value="Update Match">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just go through your binding property which would be declared in the backing bean with its getter and setter.

So you have it saved already in your backing bean of your view file.